# Angular ngFor not iterating in the right order

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

After some fetch from the backend I get an Array of arrays that I iterate to create a table using `*ngFor`. I store it in a property named "lista". This is the array of array I got:

```
0: (4) ["12.167.143-3", "Ximena Araya Guajardo", "D", "2021-04-19T04:00:00.000Z"]
1: (4) ["18.545.597-1", "Johanna Muñoz Infante", "A2", "2021-04-19T04:00:00.000Z"]
2: (4) ["12.167.143-3", "Ximena Araya Guajardo", "E", "2021-04-19T04:00:00.000Z"]
3: (4) ["23.456.789-2", "Nombre_1 ApellidoPaterno_1 ApellidoMaterno_1", "C", "2021-04-20T04:00:00.000Z"]
4: (4) ["16.134.145-8", "Luciano andres Arce Sepulveda", "A1", "2021-04-20T04:00:00.000Z"]
```

If you see, the first register is 2021-04-19 and the last is 2021-04-20.

It was working fine and rendering fine, but now I need the table to be ordered by date, the most recent dates must show first. I used this to invert the list:

```
this.listaOrderedByDate = this.lista.sort(function(a, b) {
            return (b[3] < a[3]) ? -1 : ((b[3] > a[3]) ? 1 : 0);
        });
```

where[3] is the index of the date in each array passed to the sort method.

the list got inverted:

```
0: (4) ["23.456.789-2", "Nombre_1 ApellidoPaterno_1 ApellidoMaterno_1", "C", "2021-04-20T04:00:00.000Z"]
1: (4) ["16.134.145-8", "Luciano andres Arce Sepulveda", "A1", "2021-04-20T04:00:00.000Z"]
2: (4) ["12.167.143-3", "Ximena Araya Guajardo", "D", "2021-04-19T04:00:00.000Z"]
3: (4) ["18.545.597-1", "Johanna Muñoz Infante", "A2", "2021-04-19T04:00:00.000Z"]
4: (4) ["12.167.143-3", "Ximena Araya Guajardo", "E", "2021-04-19T04:00:00.000Z"]
```

Now the arrays with elements with index 3, the date 2021-04-20, are on top and the arrays with date 2021-04-19 are on the bottom.

However, if I iterate using `*ngFor` this new property "listaOrderedByDate" in the HTML, it still prints the original array (the one named "lista"), the rendering order doesn't change at all. Although the log to the inverted array says something, the final view says another thing, I still get the oldest dates on top and the new dates at the bottom. It is not iterating in the natural order. And I can't find out why. Can you lend me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `this.listaOrderByDate` is just pointing to the same memory location as `this.lista`. You could use the [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator to allocate new memory for the `this.listaOrderByDate` array.

```js
    this.listaOrderedByDate = [...this.lista].sort(function (a, b) {
      return (b[3] < a[3]) ? -1 : ((b[3] > a[3]) ? 1 : 0);
    });
```

Comment: the code has no sense, be sure when you sort the list, if you're using mat-table or another cause